# How to get a route

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have this controller:

```
@RestController("ThresholdAdapter")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ThresholdAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    ThresholdQuery thresholdQuery;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/jbdj", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testaux() {
        
        return "lkajdfladjlksj";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/threshold/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Threshold> listThreshold(@RequestParam(required = false) String categoria, @RequestParam(required = false) String kpi, @RequestParam(required = false) String data, @RequestParam(required = false) String hora) {
        
        return thresholdQuery.listThreshold(categoria, kpi, data, hora);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/threshold/update", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Threshold updateThreshold(@RequestParam String kpi, @RequestParam String weekday, @RequestParam String hour, @RequestParam String valor, @RequestParam Boolean status) {
        
        return thresholdQuery.updateThreshold(kpi,weekday,hour,valor,status);
    }

}
```

When I call:

http://localhost:8080/jbdj

It doesn´t work.

It show the 404 Not Found error.

Comment: In which package is your controller? And your main class?

Comment: see file application.properties or application.yaml, maybe there are setting for port number and context path.

Comment: You are right, there was setting for context path. Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the annotation for rest controller  for your endpoint. Spring create a bean named  as "thresholdAdapter". You should not give any name in "RestController" annotation.

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component("thresholdAdapter")
```

Answer (score 0):

There was setting for context path.

Thanks a lot.